# Reallocation of string array in C and allocation of new strings

Tags: c, arrays, string

Does someone know what is wrong with this code? I want to reallocate an array of `char**` and then allocate space for new strings (`char*`).

```
void reallocate(char*** array, int* p_capacity) {
    int i;
    int capacityBefore;
    char **pp_tmp;
    if ((pp_tmp = (char**) realloc(*array, (2 * (*p_capacity) * sizeof (char*)))) == NULL) { 
        printf("Nedostatek pameti.\n");
        free((void*) pp_tmp);
        exit(1);
    }

    capacityBefore = *p_capacity;
    *p_capacity *= 2;

    for (i = capacityBefore; i < *p_capacity; ++i) {
        if ((pp_tmp[i] = (char*) malloc(LENGTH * sizeof (char))) == NULL) { 
            printf("Nedostatek pameti.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    *array = pp_tmp;
}
```

Comment: What error or incorrect result are you getting? What would be the correct result?

Comment: If the `realloc` fails, you try to free the pointer returned by `realloc` which is `NULL`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg which is not a problem in itself, but it can leak memory (just to be clear about that).

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Not a problem in itself, but probably not what the OP intended. Also, if the OP intends to free the pointer, the OP should probably do it if the `malloc` call fail as well, *and* free the actual strings in the array too.

Comment: The correct result would be an array which would contain the strings which were saved in the original array and space for new strings. @TheParamagneticCroissant How can I pass a pointer on 2D array to the function without using ***?

Comment: typedefs, the answer is typedefs.  At some point, you have to abstract a few things unless you want your code to be utterly unreadable. Yes `char ***` can be seen as a pointer to an array of strings, but to the naked eye, it is merely a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to a character. `StringArray` on the other hand is semantically more sensible, and it can be obtained pretty easily via typedefs.

Comment: Thanks, the code looks better, but it is not a solution for my problem. The program works for small inputs but if it tries to reallocate the array of strings it falls down because I somehow go outside of the array borders. Input: `hello
how
are
you
doing`

output: `X0,�
X0,�
are
you

RUN FAILED (exit value 1, total time: 9s)`

Answer (score 0):

I took your code and modified it very mildly (to use `size_t` in place of `int` for the size parameters, and to report errors on standard error instead of standard output), and placed it in a test harness like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { LENGTH = 32 };

static
void reallocate(char ***array, size_t *p_capacity)
{
    size_t i;
    size_t capacityBefore;
    char **pp_tmp;
    if ((pp_tmp = (char **) realloc(*array, (2 * (*p_capacity) * sizeof(char *)))) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Nedostatek pameti.\n");
        free((void *) pp_tmp);
        exit(1);
    }

    capacityBefore = *p_capacity;
    *p_capacity *= 2;

    for (i = capacityBefore; i < *p_capacity; ++i)
    {
        if ((pp_tmp[i] = (char *) malloc(LENGTH * sizeof(char))) == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Nedostatek pameti.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    *array = pp_tmp;
}

int main(void)
{
    char **array = malloc(1 * sizeof(*array));
    if (array == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Nedostatek pameti.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    array[0] = malloc(LENGTH * sizeof(*array[0]));
    if (array[0] == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Nedostatek pameti.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    strcpy(array[0], "Initial string");
    size_t size = 1;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        size_t old_size = size;
        reallocate(&array, &size);
        for (size_t j = old_size; j < size; j++)
            snprintf(array[j], LENGTH, "Additional string %zu", j);
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%2zu: %s\n", i, array[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Running it under [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) gives it a clean bill of health — apart from leaking all the memory since it does not attempt to free any of the allocated memory.

Note, however, that there were manual allocation steps in `main()` to get the allocation in motion.  If you pass a size of zero into the function, two times zero is still zero, so nothing changes.  My best guess as to your problem is that the initialization code you have (but have not shown) is not safe, or you are starting with the array size set to zero.  The next best guess is that you are copying strings longer than `LENGTH` into the data, but I regard that as less likely.

Sample output:

```
 0: Initial string
 1: Additional string 1
 2: Additional string 2
 3: Additional string 3
 4: Additional string 4
 5: Additional string 5
 6: Additional string 6
 7: Additional string 7
 8: Additional string 8
 9: Additional string 9
10: Additional string 10
11: Additional string 11
12: Additional string 12
13: Additional string 13
14: Additional string 14
15: Additional string 15
```

Please remember that you should create and post an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) — two names and links for the same basic idea — so that people can more easily understand what you see as your problem.

Testing on Mac OS X 10.9.5 Mavericks with GCC 4.9.1 and Valgrind 3.10.0.